# MenuIcon not found in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a appbar from mui which is include a MenuIcon. I've tried `import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';` from mui documentation. But it is still showing not found. so I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if you installed package with MUI icons before you installed MUI component library. Run this command:

`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

and it should help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install MUI Icons using either of the following commands.

With NPM:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

or with Yarn:

```
yarn add @mui/icons-material
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your path should be like this:

```js
import MenuIcon from '@mui/material/MenuIcon';
```